# need direction regarding jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this url which is JSON webservice 
http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2

I need to write a jquery function to access the JSON object from the above url.
I am not sure how to proceed with this task. Could someone help me out with starting out the jquery code?

Thanks

---

Inorder that the HTML appear I removed the "<" for each tag.
What I tried doing below is iterate over the items returned via the JSON object. However, I don't seem to get any result. Could some one point out my error in this regard.

body>

div id="para">

/div>

script>

$.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2',function(data) {

```
      $.each(data.weatherObservations, function(i,item){
        $("<p/>").attr("src", item.temperature).appendTo("#para");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
      });
    });
```

/script>

/body>

Thank you.

---

Hi,

I now need to access another web service. I typed out the code on the exact same lines as above but I don't get any output. Could some one help in pointing my mistake?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var url = 'http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=75080&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=ac9c073a8e025308101307';

  jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data.data.weather, function(i, item){
        $("body").append("<p>"+item.date+"</p>");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
      });
    }); 
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: To get the HTML tags to show up in your question, just indent your code 4 spaces.

Comment: To get that last one to work, use this instead of getJSON(): `jQuery.get(url, function(data) { /*...*/ }, 'jsonp');`

Comment: I'd love to see your finished product.

Comment: Thanks Mark! The entire product is a telemedicine system and this is one of the modules thats a step towards phasing in the cognition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240539/need-help-with-nested-jquery-function

Mark would you be able to point my mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as easy as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2', function(data) {
    // The JSON object is now in the data variable --
    // process it here; for example:
    alert(data.weatherObservations[0].clouds);
  });
</script>
```

Keep in mind, however, that your AJAX call must come from the same domain (ws.geonames.org), since most modern browsers do not allow cross-domain requests. The workaround is to use the JSON-P format instead of pure JSON.

... In response to rookie's edits to his original question, here is a more complete solution:

```
<html><head></head><body>
  <div id="para"></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2', function(data) {
      jQuery.each(data.weatherObservations, function(i,item){
        jQuery("<p/>").html(item.temperature).appendTo("#para");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: __Except__ that JSON-P requires cooperation from the server. It needs to return JavaScript that calls the callback you specify. So it won't work in this case.

Comment: @darkporter - it will work, getJSON appends the callback and the geonames endpoint responds with a javascript function, try
http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&callback=123

Comment: Hi, I'd really appreciate help with my edited doubted above. Thanks.

Comment: @rookie - see my edited answer. Use the jQuery html() function to put content into the paragraphs, rather than the attr() function.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'd really appreciate your help with the re-edit. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, got it: To get that last one to work, use this instead of getJSON(): `jQuery.get(url, function(data) { /*...*/ }, 'jsonp');`

Answer (score 2):

To help you read the content that's comes back, put it into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and it will format it so it is readable.

In addition to Mark's answer, you should verify the textStatus

http://jsfiddle.net/VC5c2/

```
var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=90&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2";

​jQuery.getJSON(url,function(data, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
        for (idx in data.weatherObservations) {
            var wo = data.weatherObservations[idx];
            console.log("Temperature at " + wo.stationName + ":  " + wo.temperature);
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question seems really simple. But I cannot understand why I would need to verify the textstatus? What I'm trying to ask is, what purpose does it serve? Thanks.

Comment: It is a value letting know that if it was a success.  Double check, but I think the values are "timeout", "error", "notmodified", "success", "parsererror".  If there's an error, you want to know, right?

Comment: Yeh, that makes sense. So it serves the purpose of the try catch block in java. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `jquery json` turned up this page first, which seems to be exactly what you need: [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)